# adding uri escaped xml as queryparam

Tags: apigee

Hello and thanks for any support.

So I have an API that is expecting an escaped xml as part of the query params. so I tried a couple of things.

1. `<Set>
       <QueryParams>
         <QueryParam name="xml">%3CcreateSession%3E%3CapiKey+type%3D%22integer%22%3123123123123123123%3C%2FapiKey%3E%3C%2FcreateSession%3E</QueryParam>
         </QueryParams>
       </Set>`

this actually gets extra escaped and we end up with an invalid xml

1. `<Set>
       <QueryParams>
         <QueryParam name="xml">
           <createSession><apiKey type=\"integer\">123123123123</apiKey>
           </createSession>
         </QueryParam>
       </QueryParams>
   </Set>`

this one is not even saved.

1. `<Payload variablePrefix="#" variableSuffix="#" contentType="application/json">
         { 'xml': '<createSession><apiKey type=\"integer\">123123123123</apiKey></createSession>'}
     </Payload>`

this is not helping me either.

so what would be the best way to add an xml to the params without getting extra escaped or escaped only once

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<Set>
    <QueryParams>
      <QueryParam name="xml">
        &lt;createSession&gt;&lt;apiKey type=\"integer\"&gt;123123123123&lt;/apiKey&gt;
        &lt;/createSession&gt;
      </QueryParam>
    </QueryParams>
</Set>
```